# image is not required in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey I am using this code for running my data-form to submit data in my database

It gets save when I select any image but if I don't then its goes blank and nothing gets submitted.

Below is my code

View

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/main_image_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                    <fieldset class="form-group">

                                        <input type="hidden" name="txt_hidden" value="" class="form-control"> 
                                    </fieldset>

                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="formGroupExampleInput">Add Main Caregory</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('p_name'); ?>" placeholder="Main Category" name="p_name" class="form-control"> 
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Order</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="order_id" placeholder="Order Id" value="<?php echo set_value('order_id'); ?>" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"> 
                                    </fieldset>

                                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Status ( 0 active , 1 inactive)</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Status" value="<?php echo set_value('status'); ?>" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"> 
                                    </fieldset>

                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Image</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="p_image" placeholder="Image" value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" class="form-control"> </fieldset>



                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Controller

```
function main_upload()
{
  $type=explode('.',$_FILES['p_image']['name']);
  $type = $type[count($type)-1];
  $url = "uploads/main_cat/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
  if (in_array($type,array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif")))
  {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["p_image"]["tmp_name"]))
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['p_image']['tmp_name'],$url))
      return $url; // returns the url of uploaded image.
  }
  else
  {
    redirect(base_url() . 'admin/main_cat', 'refresh');// redirect to show file type not support message
  }
}



    function main_image_upload()
{
  $data ['main_image']= $this->main_upload();
  $data ['p_name']= $this->input->post('p_name');
  $data ['order_id']= $this->input->post('order_id');
  $data ['status']= $this->input->post('status');
  $this->db->insert('main_category', $data);
  redirect(base_url() . 'admin/main_cat', 'refresh');// Redirect to Success page
}
```

If I don't choose any image then its run blank and nothing gets save in database.

how to verify the empty logic

Answer (score 0):

Put a if condition to check if user has select the image or not in you `main_upload()` function

```
function main_upload(){
    if(!empty($_FILES['p_image']['name'])){
      $type=explode('.',$_FILES['p_image']['name']);
      $type = $type[count($type)-1];
      $url = "uploads/main_cat/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
      if (in_array($type,array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif"))){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["p_image"]["tmp_name"]))
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['p_image']['tmp_name'],$url))
          return $url; // returns the url of uploaded image.
      }
      else
      {
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/main_cat', 'refresh');// redirect to show file type not support message
      }
  }else{
        return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: its give this A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'main_image' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `main_category` (`main_image`, `p_name`, `order_id`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, 'ramesh55', '3', '0')

Filename: H:/wamp64/www/digi/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: oh I miss the else condition

Comment: working but now start add blank value in other field :(

Comment: try to debug if you are getting the POST value in your `main_image_upload` function

Comment: add required in view solve issue but how i add form validation in this can you tell me ??

Answer (score 0):

You can add that condition :

```
if(!empty($_FILES['p_image']['name'])){

//Upload code

 );

}else{
//Without upload code and database field name value blank

}
```

Comment: its give me error A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'main_image' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `main_category` (`main_image`, `p_name`, `order_id`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, 'ramesh55', '3', '0')

Filename: H:/wamp64/www/digi/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: You don;t have a assign null value so error is occur please open phpmyadmin and assign main_image to null value.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should be using `form_validation` and the CI `upload` library. I mean that is one of the reasons why you choose a framework!

Alright so your view has to change a bit to accomidate session errors and the new function we are about to create:

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata(); ?>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="txt_hidden" value="" class="form-control"> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="formGroupExampleInput">Add Main Caregory</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('p_name'); ?>" placeholder="Main Category" name="p_name" class="form-control"> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Order</label>
        <input type="text" name="order_id" placeholder="Order Id" value="<?php echo set_value('order_id'); ?>" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Status ( 0 active , 1 inactive)</label>
        <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Status" value="<?php echo set_value('status'); ?>" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="p_image" placeholder="Image" value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" class="form-control">
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Scrap your `main_upload` and `main_image_upload` functions and use this:

Our new function insert uses the `form_validation` library to make sure our fields are required and set properly, you can adjust the rules to your liking the full documentation of the class is [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html).

If our validation fails we add a flash message (note: I don't have much experience with CI's flash messages to this might require some tweaking).

Than we upload the image using [CI uploader](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html). If that fails we redirect to the page with a flash message.

All else passes, than we add to the database.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
}

public function insert()
{
    // validate
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('p_name', 'Main Category', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('order_id', 'Order Id', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required|in_list[1,0]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/main_cat', 'refresh');
    }
    // validation passes, upload file
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/main_cat/'; // upload will fail if this folder doesn't exist!
    $config['file_name'] = uniqid(rand());
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('p_image')) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', $this->upload->display_errors());
        redirect(base_url() . 'admin/main_cat', 'refresh');
    }
    // upload passes, insert
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    // this should really go in a model!
    $data = array(
        'main_image' => 'uploads/main_cat/' . $upload_data['file_name'],
        'p_name'     => $this->input->post('p_name'),
        'order_id'   => $this->input->post('order_id'),
        'status'     => $this->input->post('status')
    );
    $this->db->insert('main_category', $data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Added!');
    redirect(base_url() . 'admin/main_cat', 'refresh');
}
```